# javascipt fill the missing integers from the sequence

Tags: javascript

Array given values are in ascendent order!

I want to get a arithmetic sequence with difference of 1 and the starting value should be 0.

Presumably the code provides a good solution in all cases. I think that this is too complicated solution, there must be an easier one. What could it be?

```
let arr = [{x: "a",num:4},{x: "f",num:5},{x: "k",num:7},{x: "d",num:9}];

let firstVal = arr[0].num;
let j = 0;
while(j != firstVal) {
    arr.splice(j,0,{x: "temp",num:j});
    j++;
}

let i = 0;
while(arr[arr.length - 1].num != i+1) {
    if(arr[i].num + 1 != arr[i+1].num) {
        arr.splice(i+1,0,{x: "temp",num:i+arr[0].num+1});
    }
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
0: {x: 'temp', num: 0}
1: {x: 'temp', num: 1}
2: {x: 'temp', num: 2}
3: {x: 'temp', num: 3}
4: {x: 'a', num: 4}
5: {x: 'f', num: 5}
6: {x: 'temp', num: 6}
7: {x: 'k', num: 7}
8: {x: 'temp', num: 8}
9: {x: 'd', num: 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [{x: "a",num:4},{x: "f",num:5},{x: "k",num:7},{x: "d",num:9}];

let num = 0;
while (arr.length !== 0) {
    let found = arr.findIndex(item => item.num === num);
    if (found !== -1) {
        console.log(arr[found]);
        arr.splice(found,1);
    } else {
        console.log({x: "temp", num: num});
    }
    num++;
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my code, I want to populate the array. This is just print the array's elements., thus this is no the appropriate answer.

Comment: I know that, I could make another array, and push each value into that instead of print temp out. But I think that, there must be an easier way to do it.